# JTable missing first row

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, defaulttablemodel

i already searched the whole web but I can't find a solution, so i decided to ask here.

Following problem: I am using those 2 methods to populate a JTable with a DefaultTableModel, the ResultSet shows the right amount of data entries (i already searched it with System.out.println) but the JTable always misses the first row

I am using a method to get a ResultSet like this:

```
    public static JTable DBCFillBTableAuftraege() {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    JTable table = null;

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        stmt = con.createStatement( );
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.auftrags_nr, k.firma, a.auftragsdatum, a.lieferdatum, a.rechnungsbetrag, k.name, k.strasse, k.plz, k.ort from auftrag a join kunde k on k.kunden_nr = a.kunden_nr ");
        while (rs.next()) {
            table = new JTable(tableModel(rs));
            return table;
        }   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Which then calls this method:

```
public static DefaultTableModel TableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    System.out.println(rs);
    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

In my main:

```
    TableAuftrag = DBCFillBTableAuftraege();

    scpaneBestell.setViewportView(TableAuftrag);
```

It works fine, it is showing me my column headers and the data, except one problem:

It is always missing the first row and starts with the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (rs.next()) {
    table = new JTable(tableModel(rs));
    return table;
}
```

You're consuming the first row of the result set here, and then call `tableModel()`, which consumes the other rows. The while loop is useless. Just do

```
table = new JTable(tableModel(rs));
return table;
```

Comment: thank you so much, I would have never found it myself:)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem starts here...

```
// Move to first row...
while (rs.next()) {
    table = new JTable(tableModel(rs));
    return table;
}
```

and manifests

```
// Move to second row and beyond...
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
    }
    data.add(vector);
}
```

Basically, in the first `while (rs.next())`, you move to the first row, but in the second `while (rs.next())` you move to the second row, without handling the first...

It might be better to simply pass the `ResultSet` directly to the `TableModel`.

Convention would also suggest that you probably should not need to create a new `JTable`, but instead, just create a new `TableModel` and apply to a pre-existing table

Comment: thank you so much! that was it, I would have never found it myself

Comment: @Rob987 Yep, it was sneaky one